# Handling onClick and onTouchEvent events concurrently

Tags: android, android-widget

I have a button that I handle through an onClick handler.

However, I also need to respond to onTouchEvent events so I can handle button hilighting.

The problem is, if I return "false" from my onTouchEvent handler, it will call in the onClick handler, but will never give me an onTouchEvent for the subsequent "up" event.

If I return "true" from onTouchEvent, I ill get the "up" event, but it will never dispatch the touch to onClick.

So what are my options?

1. Implement my own "click" handling inside onTouchEvent - which means that I would be required to track moves in and outside the button area, etc. Seems kind of complicated.
2. I could have my button use a selector instead of a single image, and assign different images for different states. The problem I have with this is that selectors are cumbersome to *change* the images, which I need to do. (When my app is in different "modes", the button images for different states change. Again, this seems overly complicated.

Isn't there a simple way to accomplish all this???

Comment: Let me see if I understand this correctly. You want to override a Button's default highlighting with your own? If so, can you do all your highlighting stuff within onTouch and call button.performClick() when you receive ACTION_UP? performClick calls the button's onClick method, if an onclicklistener is set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you need both click and touch events on the same view, use a [GestureDetector](http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html#detect). You should spefically look into the [onShowPress](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.OnGestureListener.html#onShowPress%28android.view.MotionEvent%29) method of its listener.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your best bet will stem from option 2, above.

I would suggest creating multiple `Button` `StateListDrawable` selectors, and then programmatically switching between styles using `Button.setBackgroundResource()`.

Comment: That's a good idea. What I actually did however was to just rewrite the entire StateListSelector every-time I wanted to change the images. However, I'd like to leave the question open, as to how to handle onClick and onTouchEvents concurrently.